# What NFC tag is used for ScripTalk "talking pill bottles"

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, medical, accessibility

Several pharmacy chains in my area have begun offering [ScripTalk](http://www.envisionamerica.com/products/scripability/scriptalk/) NFC tagged prescriptions to customers that cannot easily read prescription labels due to visual impairments, dyslexia or other reasons. Being visually impaired, technical, and volunteering my time to implement assistive technologies; I would like to know if these tags could be read by my newly acquired Galaxy S4. There's been a few NFC compatability issues with the S4 and with recent Android upgrades, so I'm curious if my phone would be able to detect AND read the NFC tags used by Scriptalk. This would indicate how likely smartphones would be to read these tags. I see a lot of use with NFC tags used for assistive tech, and using a phone as a universal NFC reader would be awesome. I have no NFC experience, so I'm hoping someone could shed some light on this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your android phone that has NFC should be able to read these ScripTalk tags, but the data on the tags is encrypted.  To my knowledge, En-Vision America (the makers of ScripTalk) considered Blind and Visually Impaired users of android, it has slowed adding an android app but since there are so few the development.  If this is something you'd like to see, I'd suggest you call Amanda at En-Vision (800-890-1180) and see if she will get it back on their development docket.

Comment: I just renewed some prescriptions and asked for scriptalk labels, so I should be able to determine what NFC tags are being used. The pharmacist didn't know what I was talking about, but the pharmacy is part of a chain that is piloting ScripTalk, and is supposed to support all branches. We'll see if this works. Thanks for the small insight into En-Vision's development strategy and contact info.